# Different Icons in List View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have to create a list view , with each item getting a separate icon along the right hand side. I have written a code , but its not working ? how do I proceed ?
application crashes

CODE

```
public class LoginMenu extends ListActivity
{

TextView maintext, subtext;
QuickContactBadge icon;

private static final String[] menuitems = { "Availability", "Messages",
"Greetings", "Address Book", "Calls", "Settings" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.menu);
maintext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMainText);
subtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSubText);
setListAdapter(new IconicAdapter());    
}    
class IconicAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{    
public IconicAdapter()
{
super(LoginMenu.this, R.layout.menu, R.id.tvMainText, menuitems);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}   
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
icon = (QuickContactBadge) findViewById(R.id.iContactBadge);
if (menuitems[0] != null)
{
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_availability);
}
else if (menuitems[1] != null)
{
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_messages);
}    
else if (menuitems[2] != null)
{
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_greetings);
}
else if (menuitems[3] != null)
{
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_contacts);    
}
else if (menuitems[4] != null)
{
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_calls);
}
else if (menuitems[5] != null)
{
icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_settings);
}
return (row);
}    
}
}
```

IMAGE My XML file contains a image , textview and another subtext arranged according to the figure below

[image: Image of the screen needed]

LOGCAT

```
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.avst.callxpressmobile/com.example.avst.callxpressmobile.MenuScreen}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:259)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at com.example.avst.callxpressmobile.MenuScreen.onCreate(MenuScreen.java:22)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
10-11 04:46:15.088: E/AndroidRuntime(726):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get simple Code here, which shows an image and some text in each row of the list:

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

[image]

but if the number of rows is high, and if the image in each row is to be fetched from a server then you better use this:

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Answer (score 6):

Just Use A `HashMap<String,String>` that will contain your row details (image, two text). Refer to this [link](http://www.tutomobile.fr/personnaliser-une-listview-tutoriel-android-n%C2%B07/04/07/2010/) that will help you to achieve what you want.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

below some links are useful to for you same code as per your requirement....

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/listview-with-images-and-text-using-simple-adapter-in-android/

http://android-example-code.blogspot.in/p/dynamic-custoized-list-view-in-android.html

http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

**OR**

```
   if (menuitems[0] != null) {
              if(menuitems[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Availability")
                {
                    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.menu_availability);
                 // Set your another textview and another subtext here....
                 }
         } 
  // Set another conditions also as per above code
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a
>   ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

You are Using `ListActivity` and also setting content `setContentView()`.  `ListActivity` by default has a `ListView` and does not needs an xml layout. However if you want to provide an xml layout, your layout MUST have a `ListView` element with id set to `@android:id/list`.

About the contents, You can always inflate a menu.xml  in a `Menu` and use it like a data Array. Luckily each `MenuItem` has a title and icon. Also `Menu` has `size()` and `getItem()` methods.